# Render js.erb from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, rendering

I have a controller action that I am trying to only render js from. Here's what I have

```
  def get_script
    respond_to :js
    render :script
  end
```

I'm using respond_to :js to hopefully force the request to only respond to js. Then I'm calling render :script to load a file called script.js.erb

My request is the following

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 15ms (ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template widgets/get_script, application/get_script with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, :html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "/home/jkoehms/TECC/tecc/app/views"
  * "/home/jkoehms/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/devise-3.5.1/app/views"
)
```

So there are two problems here. Although the request is processed as JS, the render is looking for js or html as indicated in the formats section. Secondly, the render is looking for get_script.js.erb when it should be looking for script.js.erb. I used the following documentation as a resource for rendering: [Layouts and Rendering](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#wrapping-it-up)

**Question:**

1.) Does the respond_to :js do what I'm hoping it to do, or do I have to put it in a do |format| block?

2.) Why isn't render :script looking for script.js.erb?

Comment: you do `render js: :script` .. that will work. Don't need `respond_to :js`

Comment: That gives this error  TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into String):

Comment: ok then do `render :js => 'script'`

Comment: That literally loads the javascript 'script' as vanilla javascript. I got it working with a partial   render partial: "widgets/script.js.erb"
Not the best solution

Comment: did not get you..... :/ why `partial` ? Then you should mention it.. :D

Comment: I'm doing an AJAX call to get javascript. render :js => 'script' just returns the string 'script', I need to return a js file. :partial, or :file will work if called explicitely, but the question is why doesn't :script load the file script.js.erb when that is what the documentation says (at least for html).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this inside your view?

`render "widgets/script.js.erb", format: :js`